# Github release Android project with Travis not working

Tags: android, travis-ci

We have the following `travis.yml` file:

```
language: android
android:
  components:
  - extra-android-m2repository
  - build-tools-21.1.2
  - android-21
  - sys-img-armeabi-v7a-android-21
  licenses:
  - android-sdk-license-.+
script: ./gradlew assemble
before_deploy:
  - git config --global user.email "builds@travis-ci.com"
  - git config --global user.name "Travis CI"
  - export GIT_TAG=$TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER
  - git tag $GIT_TAG -a -m "Generated tag from Travis CI for build $TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER"
  - git push -q [deleted] --tags
  - cp ./app/build/outputs/apk/*.apk .
deploy:
  provider: releases
  api_key:
    secure: [deleted]
  file:
    - "app-debug.apk"
    - "app-release-unsigned.apk"
  on:
    repo: [deleted]
    branch: master
```

However, after running the whole build I get the following message:

```
Deploying application
Already up-to-date!
# HEAD detached at ad25432
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   app-debug-unaligned.apk
#   app-debug.apk
#   app-release-unsigned.apk
#
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
Dropped refs/stash@{0} (06ce20597689d21dbeb937f9cc1ac1529ba6c14c)
/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/octokit-4.1.0/lib/octokit/client/releases.rb:86:in `initialize': No such file or directory - app-debug.apk (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/octokit-4.1.0/lib/octokit/client/releases.rb:86:in `new'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/octokit-4.1.0/lib/octokit/client/releases.rb:86:in `upload_asset'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/dpl-1.7.21/lib/dpl/provider/releases.rb:118:in `block in push_app'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/dpl-1.7.21/lib/dpl/provider/releases.rb:102:in `each'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/dpl-1.7.21/lib/dpl/provider/releases.rb:102:in `push_app'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/dpl-1.7.21/lib/dpl/provider.rb:141:in `block in deploy'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/dpl-1.7.21/lib/dpl/cli.rb:41:in `fold'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/dpl-1.7.21/lib/dpl/provider.rb:141:in `deploy'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/dpl-1.7.21/lib/dpl/cli.rb:32:in `run'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/dpl-1.7.21/lib/dpl/cli.rb:7:in `run'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/dpl-1.7.21/bin/dpl:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/dpl:23:in `load'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/dpl:23:in `<main>'
failed to deploy
```

I once set the `file:` property to `build.gradle` to test, and that worked. But why is this not working?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, found the (rather obvious, now that I see it) issue: my build output was being deleted...

I used `travis setup releases` but somehow that did not add `skip_cleanup: true` to my `deploy` block.